# Dynamically set SQL connection string based on session

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlconnection

Session variable becomes null when called from Public Partial Class outside any  methods. If called from inside the methods the value is available.
This is my code to initialize the SQL connection string but it does not work as intended.

```
public partial class Doctor_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Session["ConnectionString"].ToString());
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you setting `Session["ConnectionString"]` and what are you doing with `con`?

Comment: Session["ConnectionString"] = ConnectionString (where ConnectionString is coming from db)

string constr = HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectionString"].ToString()
con = new SqlConnection(constr)

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Is Session["ConnectionString"] null/empty?

Comment: when we are setting it, it is not null. when we retrieve it is coming null

Comment: I think an error message or clearer problem description in the question text would help this question receive better answers.

Comment: Check the page for this directive:

<%@ Page EnableSessionState="false" %>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work for you:

```
string conString;
SqlConnection con;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conString = Session["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    // Check here for conString == null, if necessary.
    con = new SqlConnection(conString);
}
```